# Error when trying to get the date on Android CallLog.Calls

Tags: android, call, android-contentprovider, calllog

Hey I'm trying to get the date from the CallLog.Calls in Android. I'm doing like this:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils;
import android.database.Cursor;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");
 int dateId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
 String callDate = cursor.getString(dateId);
 String dateString = DateUtils.formatDate(callDate);
```

But the `formatDate` method doesn't allow `String` as parameter, it needs a `Date` parameter. I've tried to make a cast, but I don't think it's right. So, someone have an idea of how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can parse the string and get a date - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for. But the date is all Jan 1, 1970. Why?? Is it the default date of the emulator? Anyways, thanks a lot. The problem was solved.

Comment: do you want to post values you're getting?

Comment: Yeah that's the default date. Date is calculated by seconds from epoch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). 0 being Jan 1, 1970.